# Clustering and Heatmap on microarray data using R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, bioinformatics, heatmap

I have a file with the results of a microarray expression experiment. The first column holds the gene names. The next 15 columns are 7 samples from the post-mortem brain of people with Down's syndrome, and 8 from people not having Down's syndrome. The data are normalized. I would like to know which genes are differentially expressed between the groups.
There are two groups and the data is nearly normally distributed, so a t-test has been performed for each gene. The p-values were added in another column at the end. Afterwards, I did a correction for multiple testing. 
I need to cluster the data to see if the differentially expressed genes (FDR<0.05) can discriminate between the groups. 
Also, I would like to visualize the clustering using a heatmap with gene names on the rows and some meaningful names on the samples (columns)
I have written this code for the moment:

```
ds <- read.table("down_syndroms.txt", header=T)
names(ds) <- c("Gene",paste0("Down",1:7),paste0("Control",1:8), "pvalues")
pvadj <- p.adjust(ds$pvalue, method = "BH")
# # How many genes do we get with a FDR <=0.05
sum(pvadj<=0.05)
[1] 5641
# Cluster the data
ds_matrix<-as.matrix(ds[,2:18])
ds_dist_matrix<-dist(ds_matrix)
my_clustering<-hclust(ds_dist_matrix)
# Heatmap
library(gplots)
hm <- heatmap.2(ds_matrix, trace='none', margins=c(12,12))
```

The heatmap I have done doesn't look the way I would like. Also, I think I should remove the pvalues from it. Besides, R usually crashes when I try to plot the clustering (probably due to the big size of the data file, with more than 22 thousand genes). 
How could I do a better looking tree (clustering) and heatmap?

Comment: define "better looking" very specifically and add a working example

Comment: I mean that the dendrogram is not messy due to too many branches. Should I only use the differentially expressed genes for the clustering and heatmap?

Comment: @newa123, definitely yes. Only use DEGs for clustering and do not cluster the pvalues. I would recommend the package `pheatmap` for clustering. Do not cluster more than ~2000 genes